# How to make my kiln airtight?

Tags: airflow, heat

I need to maintain temperatures of 900 C in a kiln. Making the kiln airtight is very important. After considerable research, I have zeroed in on sheet metal box and mylar space blankets. Am wary of using space blankets because they may get damaged by the heat. Don't prefer to use sheet metal box because they are more work to handle. Both of them will be used as a cap to surround the kiln.

Have used three layers of ceramic fiber blankets of 1 inch thickness and 96 density. Planning to add one more layer. The thermal conductivity of the blanket (probably) is in the range of 0.1 w/mk. Haven't worked out the exact R value.

Do you think mylar is suitable given that I need to keep the kiln at around 900 C for over an hour? Any other alternatives are welcome. My budget is limited so can't go for very fancy options.

Also very helpful if the permeability, diffusivity of air through the ceramic blanket can be determined. This way I will try to seal as much as possible while letting in minimal oxygen. the minimal oxygen should not be so bad.

There is a process wherein some blue chemical is applied to ceramic fiber blanket in order to harden it and make it more resistant to wear and tear. Can this process reduce the diffusivity of oxygen through the blanket?

Finally settled on sand cement plastered brick wall. This is also air tight so fine for my purposes. Will go for a sliding gate. One more step towards perfectly sealing the kiln.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Don't know why you zeroed in on Mylar when Mylar is just plastic and you can easily Google the operating temperature of Mylar. Sounds like your research has veered off track early on so you should probably start over. People tend to use fire brick and refractory  mortar.

Comment: I have mentioned my apprehensions on mylar space blankets. With enough insulation, the heating of mylar may be minimal. Am hoping someone with deep expertise and practical experience can shed more light.

Comment: It's important to note that insulation does not prevent the heat from exiting the system. It slows the rate at which the heat energy departs, which means the outside of your design will eventually succumb to the higher temperatures. An airtight kiln will require high temperature tolerant silicone gasketing in some form.

Comment: Thats why the apprehension. I can live with very low amounts of oxygen flow. I have a metallic frame in between. Will tighten it for now. I also have a different kiln which can be totally sealed without any troubles. Hence, don't want to go through unnecessary troubles of sealing this kiln.